# I just get a ball going directly upwards here, what can i change to make it work

Tags: python, simulation, physics

```
import numpy as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from IPython.display import HTML
from matplotlib import animation

#setup fig with axis
fig, ax = plot.subplots(figsize=(8,8))

#set axis limits
 ax.set(xlim=(-2,2), ylim=(0,600), xlabel="position, metres", ylabel="height, metres", title="falling apple")

#initial params
T = 100.
m = 3
g = 9.81
v0x = 10
H = 553.

#setting calc interval
dt = 0.1
N = int(T/dt)

#arrays 
v = np.zeros((N+1 , 2))
x = np.zeros((N+1 , 2))
f = np.zeros((N+1 , 2))

#array start [x ,y] format
v[0] = np.array([0. , H])
x[0] = np.array([v0x , 0.])

# the only force is gravity
f[:] = np.array([0., m * g])

#running the dynamics sim
for n in range(N):
    v[n+1] = v[n] + ((f[n]/m) * dt)
    x[n+1] = x[n] + (v[n+1] * dt)

#scatter plot
scat_plt = ax.scatter(x[0,0], x[0,1], marker='o', c='#1f77b4', s=200)

## animating 
def animate(i):
    scat_plt.set_offsets(x[i])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate, frames=N)
ani.save('ball.html', writer=animation.HTMLWriter(fps= 1//dt))
plot.close()
ani.save('ball.mp4', fps= 1//dt)
HTML('ball.html')
```

The out put is just a circle going straight up where as this is supposed to simulate a ball being thrown horizontally off a tower

It would be highly appreciated if someone could suggest any changes to be made to the logic/physics or the code.

Thank you!!

Comment: I actually did not read your code. However did you take in count that on a computer screen the y-axis in inverted (means increases by going down) and the origin is upper left point?

Comment: I did not! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed `x` with `v` at some point. Also the force should be negative in `y`. I tried this and it seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from IPython.display import HTML
from matplotlib import animation

#setup fig with axis
fig, ax = plot.subplots(figsize=(8,8))

#set axis limits
ax.set(xlim=(-200,200), ylim=(0,600), xlabel="position, metres", ylabel="height, metres", title="falling apple")

#initial params
T = 100.
m = 3
g = 9.81
v0x = 10
H = 553.

#setting calc interval
dt = 0.1
N = int(T/dt)

#arrays 
v = np.zeros((N+1 , 2))
x = np.zeros((N+1 , 2))
f = np.zeros((N+1 , 2))

#array start [x ,y] format
x[0] = np.array([0. , H])
v[0] = np.array([v0x , 0.])

# the only force is gravity
f[:] = np.array([0., -m * g])

#running the dynamics sim
for n in range(N):
    v[n+1] = v[n] + ((f[n]/m) * dt)
    x[n+1] = x[n] + (v[n+1] * dt)

#scatter plot
scat_plt = ax.scatter(x[0,0], x[0,1], marker='o', c='#1f77b4', s=200)

## animating 
def animate(i):
    scat_plt.set_offsets(x[i])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func=animate, frames=N)
ani.save('ball.html', writer=animation.HTMLWriter(fps= 1//dt))
plot.close()
ani.save('ball.gif', fps= 1//dt)
HTML('ball.html')
```